# Did Pelagius or Pelagians in General Deny Orthodox Christology

Tags: pelagianism, nestorianism

In St. John Cassian's work "On the Incarnation: Against Nestorius" he claims that Pelagius believed

> that Jesus Christ had lived as a mere man without any stain of sin, they actually went so far as to declare that men could also be without sin if they liked. ... They added as well that our Lord and Saviour became the Christ after His Baptism, and God after His Resurrection."

*On the Incarnation of the Lord Book I Chapter III. Page 552 or 553 of the second series of Nicene and Post Nicene Fathers.*

The author of this answer (https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/52958/27623) takes issue with that claim. Is this actually what Pelagius himself, or Pelagians in general believed?

It seems logical that the patristic teaching of the incarnation implicitly teaches an indwelling of grace in mankind brought about by the union of God and Man within the person of Jesus Christ and therefore this is something that the Pelagians want to deny, so they explain that Jesus Christ was simply a man that through his own will and efforts obtained the indwelling of God (sort of like a Christian version of Nietzsche's super-man) and is gracious to us by giving an example.

Comment: That quote from Cassian does not describe the Nestorian position.

Comment: @bradimus - The whole chapter has a more thorough explanation linking Nestorianism and Pelagianism. This is an explanation of Pelagianism. The core error that was shared, as he saw it, was that the divine nature did not reside in the person of Jesus Christ originally, but came later. Nestorius taught that Jesus was not born God (therefore the Virgin was not the "Theotokos") but became God later, or had God dwell in him. My question is about Pelagian Christology and if it shared this feature with Nestorian Christology.

Comment: "How therefore do I call Christ any other than God the Word, him who was born of the Father? I have said that he passed through even the blessed Mary, because he derived not the origin of  birth from her as the bodily frame which was born of her. For this reason I have said that he who is God the Word has surely passed through but was surely not born, because he derived not his origin from her. But there both exists and is named one Christ, the two of them being united, he who was born of the Father in the divinity, of the holy virgin in the humanity, for there was a union of the two natures."

Comment: Those are Nestorius's own words. God the Word passed through the Blessed Mary united to the flesh born of Mary. Read 'The Bazaar of Heracleides' before declaring what Nestorius believed. Nestorius was no adoptionist.

Comment: @bradimus - It seems your issue is with the title more than the content of the question. I've changed it so folks don't conflate Nestorian Christology with Pelagian Christology. But although I haven't read deeply into Nestorianism I am aware that there are differing opinions about the quote you give as that work was written at the end of his life, perhaps as a modification of his previous beliefs.

Comment: Nestorius did say that "Holy scripture ... speaks of the birth and suffering not of the godhead but of the humanity of Christ, so that the holy virgin is more accurately termed mother of Christ than mother of God." (http://www.monachos.net/content/patristics/patristictexts/34-patrtexts/189-nestorius-to-cyril2). Which is the whole controversy around the Council of Ephesus, because it splits Christ into two persons saying that God himself did not suffer, nor was he given birth to. Which is pretty much the same as just saying God dwelt in the body of Jesus, but the flesh was not God.

Comment: Indeed. But none that asserts that Jesus became Christ at His Baptism or God at the Resurrection. Nestorius taught a union of two natures from conception. The Orthodox objected to the type of union, not the timing.

Comment: @bradimus - Ok, that makes sense. But the question is specifically about the Pelagian belief and I changed the title to remove confusion. I  wasn't actually making any claims about Nestorian beliefs, just quoting St. John Cassian about what Pelagians believed and whether there was any other evidence of his condemnation of Pelagianism for denying Orthodox Christology. The title of the work is confusing, but that can't be helped.

Comment: Ian, love this question, but based on my learning so far, the "in dwelling" is of the Holy Spirit rather than grace ... Where is the reference for "indwelling" grace from?  Is this a matter of equivalency?

Comment: I think you need to define what you mean by "Orthodox Christology".  "Orthodox" with a capital "O" usually refers to the theology of the Eastern Orthodox Church, but somehow I don't think that's what you are looking for.

Comment: @guest37 - For the question at hand that distinction doesn't matter that much. Most any Protestant or Catholic should recognize  that claiming Jesus became God at sometime after his birth is not an orthodox or Orthodox Christology.

Comment: Quote is inaccurate, and you should reject any such baseless claims made against Pelagius. Augustine exaggerated Pelagian's views during his attacks but these are very false, cannot be substantiated. They burnt down all early writings including Pelagius coz they disagreed with their own views. They (unbelieving Jews and Christians) could not do so with the Bible otherwise they wouldn't leave anything in the bible.

Comment: @Michael16 - You seem to have some sort of special knowledge about this issue. Do you claim to know Pelagius better than those who wrote about him in his time? If you are going to accuse the saints of the church of slander and deception then I would recommend you have stronger proof than your own claims that have less foundation than Augustine's did. And this is St. John Cassian, famous for correcting Augustine's errors in his Conferences.

Comment: I dnt give em any patriarchal authority; my special knowledge is biblical verification thru which I approve Pelagius n condemn Gnostic Augustin n his cult . In the quote Cassian (1) accuses Nestorian of a belief about Christ's deity which is very questionable. (2) accuses this heresy has sprung from and same as Pelagianism, which is outright lie. Apparently he follows monergism hence exagrt Pelagian beliefs from Christ's true humanity, man's ability to piety by adding ridiculous false charges like Augustin did. Other than (1) he is right, and Pelagius was correct.

Comment: read this http://www.sullivan-county.com/z/pelagius2.htm and the other resources that show the modern evidence which favors Pelagius over the wicked traditionalists.

Comment: @Michael16 - Note the end of this article: "They saw the Augustinian theological system as a threat to grace as synergy, as a partnership between God and man. Their champion was St John Cassian, a disciple of St John Chrysostom.". This article agrees with my general perspective. It is making an argument that perhaps Pelagius himself wasn't very "Pelagian" and points out some errors in Pelagius's own thinking. You will note the quote above is from the very same John Cassian and I have clarified its context in my answer.

Comment: I can agree with Cassian's synergistic beliefs which align with Pelagius, but the claims about denying incarnation and nature of Christ is simply a lie. Those southern Gaul monks or Cassian were perhaps trying to mix monergism and synergism with bizarre theories. I think even the extreme Pelagians never taught that man can break into heaven without God's permission/approval and grace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a careful re-reading and actually looking at the footnotes of the work I found the answer myself. St John combated a developed form of Pelagianism put forth by Leporius in his own area:

> Leporius was apparently a native of Treves who propagated Pelagian views in Gaul, ascribing his virtues to his own free will and his own strength; and going to far greater lengths than his master in that he connected this doctrine of human sufficiency with heretical views on the Incarnation; thus combining Pelagianism with what was practically Nestorianism, teaching that Jesus was a mere man who had used His free will so well as to have lived without sin, and had only been made Christ in virtue of His Baptism.

This footnote is on pg 552 of the second series of the Nicene-Post Nicene Fathers (same reference as the question).

So Pelagius himself did not ascribe to these views, but the brand of Pelagianism that St. John dealt with seems to have taught this. St. John goes on in the same chapter to mention how Nestorius's own writings betray a sympathy for the views of Pelagius.

It seems to be for this reason that St. John views the Pelagian and Nestorian heresies as linked, where one will naturally lead into the other after a period of time, because if you isolate the human from the divine you inevitably start postulating that man can operate by his own power alone to attain godliness.

It is worthwhile to note that Leporius's letter of repentance and rejection of Pelagianism is included in part on the next page in which Leporius makes no mention of free-will or God's sovereignty, but only talks about the Incarnation:

> Therefore the God-man, Jesus Christ, the Son of God, is truly born for us of the Holy Ghost and the ever-virgin Mary. And so in the two natures the Word and Flesh become one, so that while each substance continues naturally perfect in itself, what is Divine imparteth without suffering any loss, to the humanity, and what is human participates in the Divine"

I think that perhaps this view was what St. John viewed as foundational to our understanding of salvation from which implicit rebukes of Pelagianism, Nestorianism, and I would think also Augustine's more extreme views can be drawn.